# Corrupt string cannot be used

Tags: c, string, fopen

I made a function to read a line from a file. The result is a printable string but when i enter the string in fopen, fopen cant find the file. I think the file path read by readline is corrupt. I hope you can help me. The code is here:

```
char *readUntilNewLine(FILE *file_stream, bool until_eof)
{     
bool stop_reading = false;
int char_counter = 1;

char *line_string;
line_string = (char*)malloc(STRING_BLOCK);

if(line_string == NULL)
{
  return NULL;
}

while(!feof(file_stream))
{    
char current_char = fgetc(file_stream);
//printf("%c\n", current_char);

if(current_char == '\n')
{
  //line_string[char_counter - 1] = '\0';
  return line_string;
}

if(char_counter % STRING_BLOCK == 0)
{
  printf("----\n");
  line_string = realloc(line_string, STRING_BLOCK * char_counter);

  if(line_string == NULL)
  {
    return NULL;
  }
}

line_string[char_counter - 1] = current_char;

printf("%d ", strlen(line_string));
printf("%c ", current_char);
printf("%d\n", char_counter - 1);

char_counter += 1;
}

if(until_eof == true)
{
  line_string[char_counter - 1] = (char)0;
}
else
{
  return NULL;
}
}
```

Comment: Please add tag with language, like C, or something

Comment: What do you mean by "fopen cant find the file" - are you getting an error message or something?

Comment: Yes, fopen cant open the path and iam sure that the path in the file is correct. readline gives me a corrupt string

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: regarding: `while(!feof(file_stream))`  the function: `feof()` does not do what you are expecting.  In general, NEVER use `feof()` in a `while()` statement.  suggest combining: `while(!feof(file_stream))
    {
    char current_char = fgetc(file_stream);`  into this: `int current_char;  while( (current_char = fgetc( file_stream ) ) != EOF )`   NOTE:  the function: `fgetc()`  returns an `int`, not a `char`

Comment: regarding: `line_string = (char*)malloc(STRING_BLOCK);`  1) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer,  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  2) need to allocate +1 more char (and the later in the code) set the final char to '\0' so will have a properly formatted string

Comment: when calling `realloc()`, always assign the returned value to a temporary variable, then check (!=NULL) that temporary variable.  Otherwise, when `realloc()` fails, the current pointer to the allocated memory will be lost, resulting in a memory leak.

Comment: the posted code never calls `fopen()`, so is very misleading.  Are you expecting the characters read from the file `file_stream` to contain a file name?  Please clarify.  This is a runtime question, so please post a [mcve]

Comment: suggest making it easy on yourself and using `getline()` to completely replace the posted function.

Comment: regarding: `if(char_counter % STRING_BLOCK == 0)`  this needs to use the actual amount of characters allocated, NOT the fixed value `STRING_BLOCK`  Because after the first call to `realloc()`, the current comparison will ALWAYS fail.

Comment: the question states that `readline()` fails, but the posted code never uses `readline()`.  please clarify

Answer (score 1):

Let's execute by hand `readUntilNewLine()` assuming that the file contains `a` `b` `c` `\n` `.` `.` `.`:

1. `stop_reading = false`
2. `char_counter = 1` (you are an optimist; most programmers at this point would have put `char_counter = 0`, because after all, you have currently not read *any* characters)
3. `line_string = malloc(STRING_BLOCK)` (the cast to `char *` doesn't buy you anything; at this point `line_string[]` contains `?????????...?`, where `?` is whatever garbage `malloc()` found there)
4. Check the result of `malloc()`
5. Check `feof()`; since you haven't read anything, it's not set. (C is not Pascal; `feof()` becomes set only *after* you try to read past the end of file.)
6. `current_char = fgetc(file_stream)` (This is `a`)
7. Not `\n`
8. Didn't fill a block
9. `line_string[char_counter - 1] = current_char`
10. `char_counter += 1` (And is now 2)
11. Check `feof()`
12. `current_char = fgetc(file_stream)` (This is `b`)
13. Not `\n`
14. Didn't fill a block
15. `line_string[char_counter - 1] = current_char`
16. `char_counter += 1` (And is now 3)
17. Check `feof()`
18. `current_char = fgetc(file_stream)` (This is `c`)
19. Not `\n`
20. Didn't fill a block
21. `line_string[char_counter - 1] = current_char`
22. `char_counter += 1` (And is now 4)
23. Check `feof()`
24. `current_char = fgetc(file_stream)` (This is the newline)
25. `current_char == '\n'` succeeds
26. `return line_string` Whoa! You return an unterminated string! At this point `line_string[]` contains `abc??????????...?`, where `?` is whatever garbage `malloc()` found there.